# How to Write Assertions for Comparing Datetime Strings with Timezone Offset

Tags: python, string, datetime, time, assert

I'm working on a Python script that interacts with a server and retrieves datetime strings. The challenge I'm facing is comparing datetime strings from my script with those received from the server. The server strings include a timezone offset, which makes direct string comparisons problematic.

Here's an example of the issue:

- My string output: `2023-10-03T01:52:04`
- Server string output: `2023-10-02T21:52:04-04:00`

I've attempted to address this issue with the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse

# My string output
my_string_output = "2023-10-03T01:52:04"
# Server string output
server_string_output = "2023-10-02T21:52:04-04:00"

# Extract the time zone offset from the server string output
offset = server_string_output[-6:]

# Parse the time strings with time zone offset
my_string_dt = parse(my_string_output)
server_string_dt = parse(server_string_output)

# Adjust for the time zone offset
if offset[0] == '-':
    server_string_dt -= timedelta(minutes=int(offset[1:]) * 60)
else:
    server_string_dt += timedelta(minutes=int(offset[1:]) * 60)

# Now, compare the adjusted date and time
assert server_string_dt == my_string_dt
```

However, the assertion is not working as expected. I'd like to write assertions to compare these datetime strings and account for the timezone offset. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the string doesn't include a timezone/offset, then what time is it even? Without knowing what timezone it's supposed to be in, you can't meaningfully compare it at all. If you *do* know what timezone it's in, then simply add that information; probably by adding a timezone to the naïve datetime object after parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of your timestamps is naïve (contains no timezone information), while the other is aware. This makes the times incomparable, since the naïve timestamp could represent a few dozen possible different points in time, depending on what timezone you interpret it in. Step 1 is that you need to know what timezone it's supposed to be in. Once you know that, you just need to add that information to the parsed `datetime` object. There's absolutely no need to manually futz around with offsets and `timedelta`s yourself.

I'm assuming your naïve timestamp is supposed to be UTC:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone

>>> a = "2023-10-03T01:52:04"
>>> b = "2023-10-02T21:52:04-04:00"

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(a)
datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 3, 1, 52, 4)

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(b)
datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 2, 21, 52, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(a).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 3, 1, 52, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(a).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) == datetime.fromisoformat(b)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a naive date/time string (one without a timezone offset/name) because the script that generates it assumes the timezone to be local. To make it comparable with another date/time string that does include timezone information, you need to convert it to one with timezone information as well. The `datetime.datetime` object conveniently offers a [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) method that can make `datetime` object aware by adding the local timezone to it when called without an argument, so you can then make a valid comparison once you have two aware `datetime` objects:

```
assert datetime.fromisoformat(my_string_output).astimezone() == \
       datetime.fromisoformat(server_string_output)
```

Comment: Datetime instances do not need to be converted to the same timezone to be comparable. As long as you're comparing either two aware or two naïve datetimes, they can be compared just fine without any conversion.

Comment: @deceze You're right indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Now you're just assuming that `my_string_output` is local time, which will produce a different timestamp on every machine it's run on.

Comment: @deceze From the wording of the question ("I'm working on a Python script ... comparing datetime strings from my script") I think it's fair to assume that the system running the OP's script that generates the value of `my_string_output` is also what's going to run the script that parses that string for comparison. Perhaps the OP can clarify it here.